# Constructing a non symmetric table

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

I am trying to construct the table as sketched out below. The placements of `X` denote entries of the table. How do I construct such a table in latex? I am happy to start to use the `multirows` package as follows:

```
   \begin{table}[h]
   \begin{center}
   \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \hline \\
   \multirow{2}{*}{X} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{X} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{X} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{X}\\
   \cline{2-7}
   &X & X & X & X & X & X \\
   \hline \\
   X & & & & & X & X \\
   \hline \\
   X & X & X & & & X & X \\
```

However, here the column lines don't join - is there a problem with the code above?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following combination of `\multirow` and `\multicolumn` might get you started:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
xxxxxxx & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{x} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{xxx} & x &\multirow{2}{*}{x}\\
\cline{1-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{xxx} & x &\\
\hline
xxx & x &\multirow{2}{*}{x}\\
\cline{1-2}
xxx & x &\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{xxx} & x &\multirow{2}{*}{x}\\
\cline{1-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{xxx} & x &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, actually upon upload my diagram was rotated and I never noticed. I've tried to construct the table I wish to draw (edited in my post) using what I read from your answer. However, there is an issue with all the column lines and rows joining up - do you know if I have a problem with my code or is this a separate issue?

Answer (score 2):

You have `\\` on both side of the `\hline`-command. That is wrong. Use `\arraystretch` and `\extrarowheight` to add height to the rows.

If you need more column width, you can use fixed width `w`-columns from the array package (`wc{1cm}`). Also, you add vertical rules command (`|`) in multicolumn only at the right side of the column definition, i.e. `c|`, except if the multicolumn spans the first column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, multirow}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}

   \begin{table}[tbh!]
\centering
   \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   \multirow{2}{*}{X} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{X} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{X} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{X}\\
  \cline{2-7}
   &X & X & X & X & X & X \\
   \hline
   X &   &   &   &   & X & X \\
   X & X & X &   &   & X & X \\
   X & X & X &   &   & X & X \\
   X & X & X & X & X & X & X \\
   X & X & X & X & X & X & X \\
   X & X & X & X & X &   &   \\
   X &   &   & X & X &   &   \\
   X &   &   & X & X &   &   \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

- You have terminated `\hline` with row terminate `\\`. Don't do this!
- Your table is not complete (missed is its end)

Bot those problem are addressed in @leandriis answer (+19. Many experts here for table design usually suggest "don't lock table contents in prison of vertical and horizontal lines. A step to "liberate" cells contents you can find in `Sveinung` answer (+1). Further step in this direction (for completeness of answers) is in MWE below, where are removed all vertical lines and for really necessary horizontal ones are used rules from the `booktabs` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}  
   \begin{table}[tbh!]
\centering % instead `\begin{center} which introduce additional vertical space
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}
   \begin{tabular}{ *{7}{c} }
   \toprule
\multirow{2.4}{*}{X} & \mcc{XXX} & \mcc{XXX} & \mcc{XXX}\\
   \cmidrule(l){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5}\cmidrule(l){6-7}
  & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
   \midrule
XX &    &    &    &    & XX & XX \\
XX & XX & XX &    &    & XX & XX \\
XX & XX & XX &    &    & XX & XX \\
    \addlinespace
XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
XX & XX & XX & XX & XX &    &    \\
    \addlinespace
XX &    &    & XX & XX &    &    \\
XX &    &    & XX & XX &    &    \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```